# typescript getting intellisense to work without classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense

New to typescript here, trying to convert this simple js to ts.

Here's my js:

```
Item = {}

Item.buy = function (id) {}
Item.sell = function (id) {}
```

I don't want to use class and I just want to use Item as a namespace.

I'm trying to get it so that when I type `Item.` it autocompletes buy or sell. I tried:

```
namespace Item {}
interface Item {}

Item:Item = {}
```

All of these give me errors.

Based on Phil's answer, this is closer to what I'm looking for:

```
interface Item {}
const Item: Item = {};

interface Item {
  buy?: Function
}
Item.buy = function () {
  Item.render()
  return "bought"
}

interface Item {
  sell?: Function
}
Item.sell = function () {
  Item.render()
  return "sold"
}

interface Item {
  render?: Function
}
Item.render = function () {
    return 1
}
```

Unfortunately this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface with the properties and method types

```ts
interface BuyAndSell {
  buy: (id: unknown) => void;  // you should use something more specific
  sell: (id: unknown) => void; // than "unknown"
}
```

then use that when declaring the implementation

```ts
const item: BuyAndSell = {
  buy: function (id) {},
  sell: function (id) {},
};
```

---

You can always create the functions at any time before creating the `BuyAndSell` implementation...

```ts
const buy: BuyAndSell["buy"] = (id) => {};
const sell: BuyAndSell["sell"] = (id) => {};

// or without explicit typings, eg
// const buy = (id: unknown) => {};

// and later...

const item: BuyAndSell = { buy, sell };
```

Comment: Thanks is something like this possible: `interface BuyAndSell {}
const Item: BuyAndSell = {};

interface BuyAndSell.buy = Function
item.buy = function () {}

interface BuyAndSell.sell = Function
item.sell = function () {}`

I would like to not put it all inside one brace set.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Why do you not want to create it like that?

Comment: @Harry I've updated my answer with something that might fit what you want

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that when I add a new method I don't want to go back and edit the original interface where it's defined, I just want to add onto the interface next to the method's definition.

Comment: I edited my question with something based on your answer, is the error there fixable?